# If $-\Delta u=f$ and $f$ is analytic, then $u$ is analytic as well.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

I know the theorem that if $-\Delta u=f$ and $f$ is analytic, then $u$ is analytic as well. The book I know that contains the proof of this theorem all use the approach with respect to complex analysis. I am wondering that is there a proof use just real analysis? i.e., without calling Cauchy-Kowalevski theorem and using complex variables...

Thank you!

Comment: Is $f$ real analytic?